# Tinymce - Blinking cursor is getting hide on a transformed(scaled) contenteditable Div

Tags: html, css, transform

**EDITED:**
I have used tinymce editor to add text with external toolbar, 
Please look into it [TINYMCE-DEMO](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/l0daab/16)
And everything is working same as i have mentioned below.

I have a transformed(scaled) div element with `contentEditable="true"`. Now the problem is when I start typing on this div box then the blinking cursor sometime get hide in Firefox, but in chrome it is working perfectly. I don't understand what is wrong with this code.
Here is my code:
HTML-

```
<div contentEditable="true" id="textbox" class="scaleDiv">Add Text Here...</div>
```

CSS-

```
<style>
#textbox { width:400px;height:250px;background:#FFC0CB;word-wrap:break-word; padding:5px;}
.scaleDiv { -moz-transform:scale(0.5,0.5);-webkit-transform:scale(0.5,0.5);}
</style>
```

And Here is the 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shailparas/6q6sc/1/)

If you move your cursor after typing from left to right or right to left then you can see the cursor - sometimes get visible and sometimes get hide.

Please Help...

Comment: Nothing appears to be wrong on my screen.

Comment: Yes it is happening in my PC, i am using FF 26 in Window 8

Answer (score 0):

It will be down to the use of different aliasing methods when scaling, or the fact that Chrome makes a concerted effort to keep the cursor alive. What is happening in FireFox is that at certain points the single vertical line (i.e. cursor) is being scaled away, this happens sometimes when using certain types of scaling, like nearest neighbour. This problem could be OS specific, I see it with the FF 26.0 on Windows.

For example:

Take this image:

[image: example lines]

And then scale it 0.75 *(I've used PhotoShop and Nearest Neighbour here, but the principal is the same)*

[image: example lines scaled]

As you can see some of the lines have vanished.

Basically you need to look into if it is possible to change the type of scaling used in FireFox and with CSS. Sadly, from what I can see so far, it is only possible for images using the `image-rendering` css property or the Microsoft non-standard `-ms-interpolation-mode`...

Comment: Thanks @pebbl for your explanation. Can i change the blinking cursor size or can i place any image on it?

Comment: Thanks again for pointing me this, i looked into it and i found this [image-rendering, -ms-interpolation-mode](http://help.dottoro.com/lcuiiosk.php) but can u tell me how can i apply this on blinking cursor.

Comment: @ShailParas -- apologies I should have made it clearer from my response, basically I don't think there is a solution at the moment. The two items I mention only affect the rendering of images, not dom elements, and especially not scaled divs with contentEditable applied. As far as I know one of the major downsides to contentEditable is that it's not very customisable, I doubt you can replace the cursor with something else. It may be worth looking into other WYSIWYG editors and see if they handle scaling.

Comment: as u suggested me to use any editor i have used tinymce and tried to do the same but result is also same, Please look into it if possible [Tinymce-Demo](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/l0daab/16)..